# Why can HMR and chunkhash not be used together?

Tags: webpack, webpack-hmr

I know that in the `webpack.config.js` the HMR plugin  and chunkhash can not be used together. But I don't know why. Can anybody explain it for me？

The wrong code is:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin =  require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    entry: __dirname + "/app/main.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/build",
        filename: "bundle-[chunkhash].js"//改为“bundle.js”及为正确的代码
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + "/app/index.tmp1.html"
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HMR, the chunk is held in memory and never emitted to disk. There is really no reason to have a hash. Now when you move to production you want that hash for cache busting purposes. Check out [Paragons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-paragons). It is using HMR and in the [Webpack config](https://github.com/joseki-tech/generator-paragons/blob/master/generators/app/templates/paragons-template/webpack.config.js) you can see it handled with:

```
filename: devMode ? '[name].js' : '[name].[hash].js',
chunkFilename: devMode ? '[name].js' : '[name].[chunkhash].js',
```